# jScrollpane not working with bootstrap selectpicker refresh method

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jscrollpane

I have tried to integrate jScrollpane custom scroll bar with bootstrap select picker dropdown. `When we remove any option element from dropdown and refresh it using selectpicker refresh method/ jScrollpane scrollbar stopped working`.

Please have a look on attached demo link to get more idea. Let me know the solution.

Demo URL : http://dropdown-test.iprojectlab.com/

jsFiddle URL : https://jsfiddle.net/ztqq0mzs/8/

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `jScrollpane` plugin is breaking when you try to apply the plugin again after you remove the selected element (Not sure why).

Also let me point out couple of mistakes in your code.

This code

```
$(document).delegate(".dropdown-toggle","click",function(){
    var jDropdown = $(this).siblings(".dropdown-menu").find("ul.dropdown-menu");
    jDropdown.jScrollPane();
});
```

**1)** You are binding the plugin for every click event, This is bad way. You need to make sure you apply it only once.

**2)** Also you are using `delegate`to bind events. This is deprecated and now you must use the `on` to bind events.

> As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method. For earlier versions, however, it remains the most effective means to use event delegation. More information on event binding and delegation is in the **[.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** method. In general, these are the equivalent templates for the two methods:

---

I have refactored your code, This is what you can do. **[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ztqq0mzs/14/)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var jDropdown = $('#country').siblings(".dropdown-menu").find("ul.dropdown-menu");
  jDropdown.jScrollPane(); // bind event on document ready, and only once

  $(document).on("change", ".selectpicker", function() {
    var selectedIndex =  $('#country').prop('selectedIndex');
    $(this).siblings(".dropdown-menu").find("ul.dropdown-menu li[data-original-index='" + selectedIndex + "']").remove();
    // directly remove the li elements of the plugin, or you can even hide them.
  });
});
```

`This bug of yours seemed very interesting (I personally spent some time debugging this).`

Comment: Thank You for your efforts and time. But I would like to notice you one thing is When you remove select option one by one then its working proper but till when you left to 4 elements. Once your select option will be left with three options its stopped working.

Comment: @TusharPamar yes I see the issue too. Sorry I didnt catch this earlier.. I will work on it and see how to fix it..